# find using multiple name patterns

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have this working fine for me:

```
find Sources/$1-$2 -name '*' |xargs perl -pi -e "s/domain.com/$2/g"
```

But when I change it to the following it doesn't:

```
find Sources/$1-$2 -name '*.php,*.rb' |xargs perl -pi -e "s/domain.com/$2/g"
```

What wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write it as:

```
find Sources/$1-$2 -name '*.php' -o -name '*.rb' ....
```

Comment: At least in my shell, it will not work without () , bash 4.1.5

Comment: find stops evaluation of the expressions (if the operator is -o) at the first one that evaluates to true. So, if you have something after the last `-name`, it wont be evaluated (if no parentheses). So, _bbaja42_ is right about the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some explanation behind the solution that others have provided.

The tests in a `find` command are combined with Boolean operators:

```
-a  -and
-o  -or
 !  -not
```

If you don't supply an operator, `-and` is the default.

```
find . -type f    -name '*.rb'  # The command as entered.

find . -type f -a -name '*.rb'  # Behind the scenes.
```

Your search failed because it didn't find any matching files:

```
# Would find only files with bizarre names like 'foo.php,bar.rb'
find . -name '*.php,*.rb'
```

You need to supply the file extensions as separate `-name` tests, combined in an `OR` fashion.

```
find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.rb'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you want all files then end in .php and .rb.

Try `find  Sources/$1-$2  \( -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.rb" \) -print |xargs perl -pi -e "s/domain.com/$2/g"`

Comment: `-iname` does it as case insensitive. I am not seeing that he needs that

Comment: @Op De Cirkel Your are correct, but I prefer using it since I've met quite a few file extensions in upper case.

Answer (score 2):

It is much better filtering out find's result with [ef]grep. Why?

Because you can fed the grep pattern as an argument, or can read it from the config or soo. It is much easier to write: grep "$PATTERN" as constructing long find arguments with '-o'. (ofc, here are situations, where find args are better), but not in your case.

The cost is one more process. So, for you example is easy to write a script myscript.sh

```
find Sources/$1-$2 -print | egrep -i "$3" | xargs ...
```

you can call it

```
./myscript.sh aaa bbb ".(php|rb)$"
```

and the result will equivalent to more complicated

```
find Sources/$1-$2 \( -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.rb' \) | xargs ...
```

**but**

why bother? If you have bash4+, (and `shopt -s globstar` in your .bashrc) you can simple write:

```
perl -pi -e '.....' Sources/aaa-bbb/**/*.{rb,php}
```

the `**` is like a `find -name`.

Comment: Egrep solution is more concise, but definitely less efficient. +1 for full perl solution.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, `xargs` is not needed here.

```
find Sources/$1-$2 \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.rb' \) \
   -exec perl -i -pe "s/domain\.com/$2/g" {} +
```

Also notice the "`.`" in /`domain.com`/ needs to be escaped.

Comment: yes, not needed. BUT, with the -exec you will do expensive (fork/exec) with a "big" perl for each file. While with the xargs maybe only one times. (or few times, based on arglist length). Therefore, imho, it is better avoiding costly perl startup for each file, - and using xargs is faster.

Comment: @jm666, You're thinking of `-exec ;`. `-exec +` does the same as `xargs`.